# Vue.js - How to align the table header titles and the rows?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnXq3.jpg)

I'm trying to align the table headers with the the table content. Anyone know the best way to do this - I'm been trying for 2 hours without getting anywhere.

Edit: The code is [here](https://bitbucket.spotlightsportsgroup.com/projects/ICS/repos/buzzbingo_trolled_celebs_dev/browse) if anyone wants to take a look...

This is the CSS for the column header

```
.column-header {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}
```

This is the CSS for the table row

```
font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: text-align: center; or show us HTML + all CSS file

Comment: Its a landing page built on Vue. https://bitbucket.spotlightsportsgroup.com/projects/ICS/repos/buzzbingo_trolled_celebs_dev/browse

Comment: is there a demo somewhere which can I see to try? :)

Comment: @Parker the URL you have provided does not work for me.

Comment: Please add HTMl in your question, your Bitbucket URL can not be accessed [ask]. It would be nice if you can post your HTML right here

Comment: @LuboMasura Link should work now

Comment: @Parker it does not, after I log in it gives me Error: app_not_configured_for_user

Comment: could you please add my email address as a contributor so I can check? lubosmasura@gmail.com

Comment: @LuboMasura It won't give me access. I'll send you the source code in a zip file to your email. Hope thats ok.

Comment: It appears that you are using `display:flex` for your table. Have you tried playing around with `justify-content`? @Parker

Comment: @Parker ok send

Comment: @HuyPhạm I have. But still doesn't work.

Comment: @LuboMasura Just sent it you

Comment: @Parker there is no HTML in the file just some file without any format.

Comment: @Parker I need to see the HTML

Comment: @LuboMasura Its built on Vue.js. HTML file is under Public > index.html

Comment: @Parker I dont work with vue.js so what I need to see in this question is your html and css code so we could see the problem and solve it.

Comment: @LuboMasura These are all the files in the project. I don't know what else to give...

Comment: @Parker see how to post a regular question on stack overflow. You should provide your html code here and css code, I see only the css code here.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `text-align: center;` to the *column-header* class.

Answer (score 0):

Select `td` and `th` tag from Html and add the `text-align: center;` into CSS this will make the whole header and its content into the center.